# Parsing an XML element in javascript/jq

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml

```
<action id="118" type="move" shipID="251" X="29" Y="0" rotate="90" />
```

I have been stuck too long on this - The above xml string is the whole ajax response I get, but I cannot parse the attributes. I keep getting either errors, or undefined or [object] [Object] and I have tried so many stuff...

Problem might be that I only have 1 tag with attributes...

Comment: _"The id attribute value **must begin with a letter in the roman alphabet** (a–z or A–Z); this can be followed by any combination of letters (a–z or A–Z), digits (0–9), hyphens (-), underscores (_), colons (:), and periods (.)."_ http://reference.sitepoint.com/html/core-attributes/id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Jquery [.parseXML()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/)

```
var xml = '<action id="118" type="move" shipID="251" X="29" Y="0" rotate="90" />';
var doc = $.parseXML(xml );

var id = $(doc).find('action').attr('id');
var shipID = $(doc).find('shipID').attr('id');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//I separated these variables so that you can read it easily
var xml = '<action id="118" type="move" shipID="251" X="29" Y="0" rotate="90" />';
var $doc = $.parseXML(xml);
var $xml = $($doc);

//then
var id = $xml.find('action').attr('id');
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/RKe75)

If you are OK with html parsing of the string then

```
//I separated these variables so that you can read it easily
var xml = '<action id="118" type="move" shipID="251" X="29" Y="0" rotate="90" />';
var $xml = $(xml);

//then
var id = $xml.attr('id');

console.log(id)
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/f8eSE/)